# Flutter better player how to use onControlsVisibilityChanged

Tags: flutter, dart, video-player

im using better player and i want to build my own custom controls but i don't know what i have to do with this parameter  `customControlsBuilder: (controller, onPlayerVisibilityChanged) =>` this param `onPlayerVisibilityChanged` how do i use it?

here is my code, im using `CustomControlsWidget` from the documentation but there is no clues on how use this `onPlayerVisibilityChanged`

```
  controlsConfiguration: BetterPlayerControlsConfiguration(
              controlsHideTime: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
              controlBarColor: Colors.black12,
              playerTheme: BetterPlayerTheme.custom,
              customControlsBuilder: (controller, onPlayerVisibilityChanged) =>
                  CustomControlsWidget(
                controller: controller,
                onControlsVisibilityChanged: onPlayerVisibilityChanged,
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to make a custom Control class. Have a look at this example [here](https://github.com/jhomlala/betterplayer/blob/master/example/lib/pages/custom_controls/custom_controls_widget.dart).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34082633)